# CSS Div auto increase height

Tags: html, css

I want to place three divs one below the other.
i.e basically want to avoid any page scrolling except for the middle div.

http://jsfiddle.net/2ay2p/

```
<div id="one">

</div>
<div id="two">

</div>
<div id="three">

</div>

#one{
    width:100%;
    height: 10%;
}
#two{
    width:100%;
    height: 80%;
}
#three{
    width:100%;
    height: 10%;
}
```

I want the center div to take full height even if the content height is less than 80%.
If content height > 80%; I want a scrollbar to appear.

How can I achieve this with pure css?

Comment: Can you provide more detail? Like with view example.

Comment: 80% is less than the normal 100%. Are you talking about `px` ?

Comment: Nope. I want height to be in percentages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close, you just have to add height and width for the body and html to make this work. Try the demo below.

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2ay2p/4/)

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

also add `overflow:auto;` on your middle div to enable scroll.
Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/2ay2p/7/) demo for long text.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `overflow:auto` for Scoll Bar and see demo below second div taking full height

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/2ay2p/5/)

[DEMO With ScrollBar](http://jsfiddle.net/2ay2p/8/)

Comment: I did not wanted to hardcode the height for any div.

Answer (score -1):

Use margin: 0 auto. It display div in center

Comment: The question is to avoid scroller. Not to display center.

Comment: OP is asking different